# unwanted spaces in x-axis of a histogram plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I wanted to create a histogram with a series of integer data. So because of a large range in the x-axis, I decided to use a logarithmic scale for the x-axis. But there is a space between "1", "2", and "3" numbers in the plot. Could anybody help me with the reason and tell me how to remove these spaces?

Here is my code:

```
H1 <- as.data.frame(floor(runif(10000, min = 1, max = 100)))
colnames(H1) <- "H"
breaks <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,100,500,1000,max((H1$H)))

ggplot (H1, aes(H)) + 
  geom_histogram(colour="darkgreen", size=1, fill="green", binwidth = 0.1) + 
  stat_bin(geom="text", aes(label=..count..) , hjust=-0.4, vjust = 0.4, binwidth = 0.1 , angle = 90, size = 2.5) + 
  scale_x_log10('Integer Data', breaks = breaks, labels = breaks, expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.01))) +
  scale_y_continuous('Count', expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.1))) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 8, angle = 60, vjust = 0.8, hjust=1))
```

And it is the output:

[image]

Comment: If you expect to not have a larger space between 1 & 2 than between 2 & 3, and a larger space between 2 & 3 than between 3 & 4, and so on, maybe you don't actually want a logarithmic scale. That's how log scales work by definition. You're also not going to have bins that align with all those integers.

Answer (score 1):

When you use a logarithmic scale for a histogram you have to make sure that there are a *reasonable* number of elements within each bin.
You have generated your data with `runif`, so a uniform distribution. This means that between 1 and 10 there will be far fewer elements than between 10 and 100.
Since you have fixed a certain number of `breaks` and a certain `binwidth` you are getting empty bins.

What you can do is change `binwidth` or number of `bins`. Eg:

```r
ggplot(H1, aes(H)) + 
  geom_histogram(colour="darkgreen", size=1, fill="green", bins = 10) + 
  stat_bin(geom="text", aes(label=..count..) , hjust=-0.4, vjust = 0.4, bins = 10 , angle = 90, size = 2.5) + 
  scale_x_log10('Integer Data', expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.01))) +
  scale_y_continuous('Count', expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.1))) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 8, angle = 60, vjust = 0.8, hjust=1))
```

I removed `breaks` and `labels`, because the center of the bin no longer falls on integers.